# Ubuntu Server Default Security on AWS

Tags: node.js, security, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I'm totally new to Linux but have been developing on windows platforms for years. I'd like to set up an Ubuntu server on AWS to house Node.js.  If I run through the default install for Ubuntu server, load Node.js and start up a simple Node.js server on port 80 is there anything else I need to do to secure the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to harden a server, I will only name two that are *absolutely* necessary.
On Ubuntu server there might or might not be activated already, but you should always check.

### Activate a firewall

The simplest way to handle `iptables` rules for firewall is `ufw`. Type in your terminal:

```
ufw default deny  # Silently deny access to all ports except those mentioned below
ufw allow 22/tcp  # Allow access to SSH port
ufw allow 80/tcp  # Allow access to HTTP port
ufw enable        # Enable firewall
ufw reload        # Be sure that everything was loaded right
```

Be sure to allow SSH, otherwise you will be **locked outside** your server. Also note that UFW (and iptables) allows to allow or deny single IP addresses and subnetworks.

### Force pubkey login in SSH, disable root login and use fail2ban

Password login is weak if an attacker can try accessing your server anytime, unless you use a long and impossible-to-remember pseudo-random sequence. SSH allows to handle authentication via public/private keys, which are more robust and far less predictable, being generated from a random seed.

First generate your own pair of keys and add your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server, so that you are not locking yourself out. After, and only after, have a look at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. The two relevant options are:

```
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

This way, the attacker must guess the username of the administrator before even trying the password, because they cannot login as root. You don't need to access as root to get root privileges, you will be able to elevate from your user account with `su` or `sudo`.

Finally, use `fail2ban` to temporarily ban by IP address after a certain number of wrong attempts to authenticate (so that attackers cannot brute force that easily). I said temporarily because if an attacker spoofs your legitimate IP, he/she can perform a DoS on you.

After applying all changes, restart the daemon with:

```
service ssh restart
```

I will repeat it, **be careful, check everything or you will lock yourself out of your server**.

### Other remarks

A default Debian/Ubuntu installation is secure enough to be exposed on the Internet without fearing any major flaw. Still, you should *always* review security settings, gather information about software you are deploying on the server and periodically inspect logs searching for abnormal patterns.

Other tools that might be useful are Apparmor, providing MAC profiles for most system services (Postfix, HTTPd...), LXC for sandboxing, chroots, etc... It depends on how critical the infrastructure is.

Comment: Thanks Stefano, I appreciate your help.  Eventually I'll get into the Linux swing of things but until I do people like you are a great help.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this topic is too wide for a SO answer.
The best place to start would be probably to start mapping the security best practices and the required knowledge for you to gain.

Knowledge Centers:

1. [CSA - Cloud Security Alliance](https://cloudsecurityalliance.org/): The place to have full understanding of what is required to run a server in the cloud.
2. [OWASP - Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/). Deals with your web app. Take a look at the [top 10 list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10)
3. [PCI - The payment card industry regulator.](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/) Though you are probably not storing credit cards - this is a good source to learn. Here is an [intro.](http://www.secureconsulting.net/2009/02/pci_dss_v12_in_a_nutshell.html)

Now you have several approaches to deal with it:

1. Enterprise approach - learn, plan, implement, test, create ongoing processes.
2. Guerrilla approach - Iterative: find the lowest hanging fruit and handle it.
3. Hybrid - combine some properties from both approaches.

Regarding your lowest hanging fruit / most critical attack vectors:

1. Your Perimeter aka Proper Firewall Configuration - since you are running on AWS you should consider using their powerful network based FW (aka Security Groups). For simple use-cases you can use their console UI. For more complex setups you might want to add dedicated security management services such as [Dome9](http://www.dome9.com) that could assist with management of both network based and host based security policies.
2. Utilize WAF (Web application firewall) - consider either using [mod-security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) - host based WAF that can be installed on your nginx that (hopefully) sits in front of your nodejs. OR alternatively use WAF as a service by [Incapsula](http://www.incapsula.com/) or [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)
3. Setup proper centralized logging. Compare Splunk Cloud, Sumo Logic, LogEntries and Loggly to find your service of choice.
4. Harden your server authentication and accounts (too long to cover here)